# VBA поиск точных данных

Tags: excel, vba

Макрос ищет на листе "Чел из формы" заданные данные (в шапке таблицы), берет номер столбца где найдено совпадение и копирует столбец на лист "Чел".
Проблема: одно из значений поиска "КЛ", такие буквы встречаются в "НоменКЛатура", поэтому макрос забирает этот столбец. Как сделать поиск только по точному совпадению?

```html
Sub test()
    Dim currColumn As Object
    Dim mstr As String

    With Worksheets("Чел из формы")
        For i = 1 To 9
            mstr = Array("Товарная группа", "Номенклатура", "Название номенклатуры", "КП", "*КЛ", "Статус номенклатуры", "Розничная цена", "Ост. ЦС", "Объем")(i - 1)
            Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr, SearchFormat:=False)
            .Columns(currCell.Column).Copy Worksheets("Чел").Columns(i)
        Next i
    End With
    
    With Worksheets("Нвс из формы")
        For i = 1 To 9
            mstr = Array("Товарная группа", "Номенклатура", "Название номенклатуры", "КП", "КЛ", "Статус номенклатуры", "Розничная цена", "РЦ Ост.", "Объем")(i - 1)
            Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr, SearchFormat:=False)
            .Columns(currCell.Column).Copy Worksheets("Нвс").Columns(i)
        Next i
    End With

    Worksheets("Чел").Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 40
    Worksheets("Чел").Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 5
    Worksheets("Чел").Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 40
    Worksheets("Нвс").Columns(1).ColumnWidth = 40
    Worksheets("Нвс").Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 5
    Worksheets("Нвс").Columns(3).ColumnWidth = 40
    Set currColumn = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: `.Cells.Find(What:=mstr, SearchFormat:=False, XlLookAt := xlWhole)`?

Comment: @akina ошибка 448 named argument not found

Comment: Пардон, свойство имеет имя LookAt. Мог бы и сам посмотреть, между прочим...

Comment: спасибо, я загуглил XlLookAt, нашел, что такое свойство есть, подумал проблема не в ошибки имени)

Comment: *я загуглил XlLookAt* Чё сразу гугл-то? тоже мне эксперта нашёл... А просто поставить курсор в середину слова Find в редакторе VBA и нажать F1 не пробовал?

Comment: Неа, сейчас попробовал, нашел что такое поиск, но про свойства типа LookAt слов нет)

Answer (score 0):

[Документация по вызову метода Range.Find](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/vba/api/excel.range.find?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Dru-RU%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm144128)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

Вообще в VBE (редакторе VBA) есть встроенный справочник api объектной модели. 
В меню нужно выбрать `View -> Object browser` (или нажать `F2`). Появится вот такое окно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В поле 1 вводите искомый метод / свойство, жмете кнопку поиска 2, выбираете результат 3, или ищите в списке объектов и их методов 4, внизу можно посмотреть синтаксис вызова 5 и по нажатию кнопки 6 получить развернутую справку с подробными разъяснениями

В вашем случае, согласно документации, как и советовали в комментариях, достаточно изменить следующую строку:

```
Set currCell = .Cells.Find(What:=mstr, SearchFormat:=False, LookAt:=xlWhole)
```